# Is the local variable in the thread function similar to the thread-local variable?

Tags: c, multithreading

Is the local variable in the thread function similar to the thread-local variable?

Let's say I have the below snippet of C code, my question is whether the variable `j` in the thread function "run" is similar to the global thread-local variable `i`? Does it mean the modifications to them are all thread-safe?

```
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdio.h>
thread_local int i = 10;
int run(void* v) {
  int j = 10;
  i = 0;  // thread safe?
  j = 0;  // thread safe?
  printf("%d\n%d", i, j);
  return thrd_success;
}
int main(void) {
#if !defined(__STDC_NO_THREADS__)
  thrd_t thread;  
  thrd_create(&thread, run, NULL);
  thrd_join(thread, NULL);
#endif
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is, a local variable is unable to be accessed concurrently.

Comment: @273K A local variable _can_ be accessed concurrently -- all you need to do is pass its address to another thread. In practice this happens quite a lot.

Comment: @EmployedRussian If you pass its address, you do not have access to a variable, but have access to its storage.

Answer (score 2):

> my question is whether the variable j in the thread function "run" is similar to the global thread-local variable i?

Depends on what you mean by "similar".

> Does it mean the modifications to them are all thread-safe?

Yes, modifying either `j` or `i` is thread-safe<sup>1</sup>.

The major difference is that `i` is persistent (like a global) for the duration of the thread, while `j` only exists while `run` is running.

In your program the lifetime of `run` and that of the thread are (almost) the same, but it's trivial to construct an example where `i` lives much longer than `j` and is used across multiple functions.

---

<sup>1</sup> If you pass the address of either `i` or `j` to a different thread, then neither of them would be thread-safe on its own and you would need to synchronize the access or you'll get a data race.

Comment: BTW, what's the difference between retrieving TLS data by simply "=" and tss_get function?

Comment: @JasonYu `tss_get()` requires that you use `tss_set()`, and is more clunky. There is no _practical_ difference; `thread_local` simply makes this less clunky.